# Gmail 'All Mail' only showing 10 days of mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

Yesterday I went into the 'All Mail' folder in Gmail and I noticed that the mail listed only went back 10 days.

I try to follow the "Inbox Zero" approach to mail management and archive all the mail that has been addressed in my inbox, but sometimes these archived emails need to be referenced at a later date. I tried to find an older email while with a client yesterday, but I couldn't find it because it was older than what All Mail was willing to load, and I couldn't remember the sender's email address for search.

Is this a configurable behavior, or am I not aware of some Gmail limit for All Mail?

Comment: "All mail" is literally all of your mail. If it only shows 10 days worth, then either that's all there is or there's a rendering problem. For the latter, have you tried a different browser? For the former, did you check your Trash to see if it was all there? Have you given access to your email to any third-party that may have deleted the messages?

Comment: @ale I've tried on multiple browsers, and checked the trash. Just noticed that even the trash folder is seeing this problem; I can only see the trash back to Sept 30th right now. It appears to be a quantity limit.. both only show 50 emails. Everything beyond that is inaccessible

Answer (score 0):

Oh my I figured it out with help from [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/oTzQ7kVRP10/P0oadYaQ8XQJ).

It turns out I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how Gmail loads mail... Every client that I've used in the past automatically loads more mail once you're approaching the end of what's been loaded, allowing you to continually scroll indefinitely. Not the case with Gmail.

**To load more mail you have to hit the left or right arrow in the top-right corner of the message window. This showed the additional mail that I had been missing.**

Problem resolved, but this seems very unintuitive to me.

Comment: "Every client that I've used in the past automatically loads more mail once you're approaching the end" - Interesting, I've _never_ encountered a "desktop" email client that works like that! "this seems very unintuitive to me" - granted, I've always thought that navigation controls were missing from the end of the list. However, with the new Gmail interface, the navigation controls are at least permanently visible in the toolbar at the top (this never used to be the case).